# Multi_line_string stay nil after update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgis, rgeo

I added a multi_line_string field in my database :

```
t.geometry "zmpath", limit: {:srid=>4326, :type=>"multi_line_string", :has_z=>true, :has_m=>true}
```

If I update my table by pgAdmin, the result is persisted but the field stay empty on my update form.

But if I try to update the field by erb or via my app, the field stay nil but I get this error :

```
[59] pry(main)> Track.find(9).update_columns(zmpath: "MULTILINESTRING ZM ((0 0 4 6,5 5 4 6),(10 10 4 6,5 5 4 6,0 0 4 6),(0 0 4 6,10 10 4 6,10 0 4 6))")
  Track Load (5.3ms)  SELECT "tracks".* FROM "tracks" WHERE "tracks"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
NoMethodError: undefined method `factory' for nil:NilClass
from /Users/ben/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/rgeo-2.3.1/lib/rgeo/wkrep/wkb_generator.rb:101:in `generate'
```

All other geoms work fine on this table

**rgeo.rb**

```
RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.tap do |config|
  config.default = RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326)
end
```